# Intercepting request to force new tab in Chrome Web Extension causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I work with a system that has some annoying navigational behaviour, it's a RESTful back-end so I had the idea of building a Chrome Web Extension which would catch specific URLs, and force them into a new tab.

Using a background script in the WebExtension I catch the requests using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, then I use `chrome.tabs.query({"active": true,"currentWindow": true}`, with a callback to get the Index of the current tab. In the callback I use `chrome.tabs.create` to open a new tab with the exact same URL as the initial request, unfortunately opening the new tab also fires the `onBeforeRequest` listener which starts the infinite loop.

Does anyone know of a mechanism I can use to stop this?

Comment: Add a dummy parameter to the URL's query (after `?` or `&`) like `chrome.runtime.id + '=yes'` or simply store that new tab's `id` in a global variable and check it in the onBeforeRequest listener, clear the variable?

Comment: I was eventually able to solve it by using the frameId field in the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` callbacks's parameter. FrameId has a positive integer when the request comes from a user clicking a link in a page and is zero when the request comes from a `chrome.tabs.create` or `chrome.tabs.update`.